# Wait for button press (in GUI) to advance in the code

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, thread-safety

thanks to the helpful replies here, I've got my GUI the way I wanted it to be.
--> [How do I create the following GUI in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143938/how-do-i-create-the-following-gui-in-java-swing)

The problem I'm currently having is, how do I "interrupt" the execution of my code and tell my code to wait[image]

That is the GUI and the this is the current code with an added ActionListener:

```
import java.awt.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  

public class GUITest extends JFrame {

JButton testButton1 = new JButton("Do something");
JButton testButton2 = new JButton("Do something different");
JButton testButton3 = new JButton("Do something even more different");

 public GUITest() {

      super("Testing Title");  
      Container pane = getContentPane();  
      pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      pane.add(getHeader(),BorderLayout.NORTH); 
      pane.add(getTextArea(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
      pane.add(getButtonPanel(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);

}  

 public JComponent getHeader() {  

     JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();  
     labelPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));  
     labelPanel.setSize(getPreferredSize());    
     JLabel labelLocal = new JLabel("Left value: ", JLabel.CENTER);  
     JLabel labelDB = new JLabel("Right value: ", JLabel.CENTER);  
     labelPanel.add(labelLocal);
     labelPanel.add(labelDB);
     return labelPanel;

  }

public JComponent getTextArea() {  

   JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();    
   textPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,5,0));

   JTextArea testTextArea = new JTextArea();
   testTextArea.setEditable(false);
   JScrollPane sp1 = new JScrollPane(testTextArea); 

   JTextArea testTextArea2 = new JTextArea();
   JScrollPane sp2 = new JScrollPane(testTextArea2); 
   testTextArea2.setEditable(false);

   testTextArea.setText("Hello Hello Hello\nTesting!\ntesterino\ntesteroni");
   testTextArea2.setText("Hello Hello Hello\nTesting!\ntest\nABC123\ncdef123\nhijk123");

   textPanel.add(sp1);
   textPanel.add(sp2);
   return textPanel;
}

 public JComponent getButtonPanel() {

  JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
  buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  testButton1.addActionListener(this); 
  testButton2.addActionListener(this); 
  testButton3.addActionListener(this); 

  buttonPanel.add(testButton1);  
  buttonPanel.add(testButton2);  
  buttonPanel.add(testButton3);  
  return buttonPanel;   
}

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
if(event.getSource() == this.testButton1){
    System.out.println("testButton1!");
}

if(event.getSource() == this.testButton2){
    System.out.println("testButton2!");
}

if(event.getSource() == this.testButton3){
    System.out.println("testButton3!");
}
}  

public static void main(String[] args) {  

  GUITest e = new GUITest();  
  e.setVisible(true);  
  e.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(650, 200));
  e.pack();  
  e.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
  e.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
  }  
}
```

I've read something about using JOptionPane but apparently that does not give me the flexiblity that I want, since I not only want buttons but two labels and **text areas** as well.

Basically, what I want to do is this:

```
//...
//other code that comes before

GUITest.openGUI();
if(button1 == pressed)
{
  //do something and hide GUI
}
else if(button2 == pressed)
{
  //do something else and hide GUI
}
//afterwards, there is more code, but it only gets executed after a button press
```

I want the execution to stop **until** I have chosen to press either Button1 or Button2. I don't want to do wait() since that would probably be bad performance wise.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have to change your way of thinking. GUI-Applications work Event-Driven. That is: In principle it is "waiting" constantly. A pressed button will raise an event for which you can register a handler. That handler's code will be executed as soon as the respective event occurrs.

Answer (score 3):

> I've read something about using JOptionPane but apparently that does not give me the flexiblity that I want, since I not only want buttons but two labels and text areas as well.

Then you will want to read a bit more about JOptionPane, since it can certainly display all these animals and more. Understand that the Object parameter of the `JOptionPane.showXxx(...)` method can take any Swing component as its value. This means that the JOptionPane can accept and display a JPanel that is filled with multiple components including other JPanels, that in fact can contain an entire complex GUI. [For example, please look at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6555051/522444).

The other option is to create your own JDialog, make it modal and display your halting GUI within this; either would work.

---

> Basically, what I want to do is this:
>
> ```
> //other code that comes before
> GUITest.openGUI();
> if(button1 == pressed)
> {
>   //do something and hide GUI
> }
> else if(button2 == pressed)
> {
>   //do something else and hide GUI
> }
> //afterwards, there is more code, but it only gets executed after a button press
> ```

Here you may be mistaken in how event-driven programs work. There's no need to "wait" for anything here, but rather you *react* to events, such as button pushes, when they occur. The key is to use your listeners to react to button pushes, and alter the behavior of this reaction depending on the *state* of your program.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You say that JOptionPane can accept any JPanel. So it would be possible to put the GUI I already have into a JOptionPane? And if yes, which one do I use? showOptionDialog?

Comment: Also, for your edit: I've maybe worded it incorrectly but there is certaintly a need in "waiting". Basically I want the program (which does something else) to display a small GUI / Dialog and let the user choose what he wants to do and according to that, the program progresses further. It waits for user input.

Comment: JDialog waits for user input, which is exactly what I want. How do I "convert" the above mentioned code into a JDialog which looks exactly the same? Thanks.

Comment: @OldMcDonald: I avoid creating classes that extend top level windows such as JFrame or JDialog, since that paints you into a corner. Instead have the class extend or create a JPanel, get all JFrame code out of it, and then put it into a JOptionPane, or create a JDialog on the fly and place it into that.